# Why are Wake On Lan scheduled deployments not working SCCM 1802?

Tags: sccm, wake-on-lan

Wake On Lan is enabled, subnet directed broadcast method, port = 9 (I've tried several other ports).

I've worked with my network team to allow subnet directed broadcasts, and it does work using Right Click Tools (run from server) using same subnet directed broadcast method and same ports, including port 9.

Scheduled deployments are set to Wake Up but when the deadline passes the computers do not wake up.  I have two other SCCM servers that I'm able to run scheduled deployments on just fine.

I've disabled Wake On Lan, monitored to make sure it is removed, enabled it again, monitored to verify it finishes installing, but it still isn't working.

I have rebooted the server as well.

Comment: I have an open ticket and have begun working with MS support today.  Will post back details as things progress.

Comment: The solution is too long to post here.  See this thread instead:

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6c7dcac5-5b97-4899-a9b3-fde5b7352eb2/wake-on-lan-scheduled-deployments-not-working-sccm-1802?forum=ConfigMgrCBGeneral&prof=required

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a bug in SCCM Current Branch 1802, and there was no charge for my Microsoft Premiere Support ticket. We did get the problem resolved.

**There were two missing registry keys, and a missing folder**, that appeared to be the culprit. We did add/change a couple of other keys, but they did not change the symptoms at all.

From MS Support:
"*CB 1802 is lacking the following registry keys (exported from my UPGRADED environment):*"

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SMS\Inbox Source\Inbox Definitions\77]

"Inbox Name"="SMS_AMT_PROXY_WOL"

"Location Type"=dword:00000001

"NAL Path"=""

"Relative Path"="inboxes\amtproxymgr.box\wol.box"

"Service Rights"=dword:00000054

"User Rights"=dword:00000000

"Guest Rights"=dword:00000000

"Monitoring Enabled"=dword:00000001

(and)

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SMS\Inbox Source\Inbox Instances\77]

"Inbox Name"="SMS_AMT_PROXY_WOL"

"Location Type"=dword:00000001

"Assistant Flags"=dword:00000000

"NAL Path"=""

"Relative Path"="inboxes\amtproxymgr.box\wol.box"

"UNC Path"="\\PRI1.CONTOSO.LOCAL\SMS_P01\inboxes\amtproxymgr.box\wol.box"

"Monitoring Enabled"=dword:00000001

On my server I had to add the two keys by creating new keys using the next available number in Inbox Definitions and Inbox Instances (mine was 76).

I also had to create the wol.box folder inside of the amtproxymgr.box folder. I simply copied the existing folder named "bad" and named it wol.box.

Make sure the UNC path has your actual server FQDN name AND SCCM site name share. The above example is from the MS support person's test install.

Yes the double backslashes are there for single backslash, and quadruple for double. Not sure why but that is how many reg keys work.

As soon as I had these registry keys and the wol.box folder, the persistent errors that had been occurring every five seconds, immediately ceased and new data showed in the log that matched what I see on my other two server.